# using SQL to directly delete CoreData data from my DB

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite, core-data

There are times when i will need to delete say 10,000 rows from my CoreData data store and looping through those records individually each time takes way too long.

Is there a way to use SQL to directly delete from my data store quickly?

Comment: can you post the code you are using?  and if you can't, are you saving after each delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the CoreData store directly risks corrupting the database and is very highly discouraged. Your best bet is to delete with a CoreData query that is able to select all of the rows to be deleted at once.

When I say it risks corrupting, I don't mean that anything would be wrong with your SQL query, but that CoreData also inserts a lot of metadata into the database to help its indexing.

Comment: that's what I figured, as far as I know I have to load all of the objects I want to delete and then loop through them to delete them all - very slow.

Comment: You should be able to load them all into an array at once, then do a for statement marking them all as deleted, then doing a commit every once in a while. You should probably commit every 100 records or so if possible to keep your memory footprint down. You may also need to page your load rather than getting them all at once with that many records.

Comment: yeah, it is still kinda slow when dealing with 10,000+ records - I'll play with the batch size and commit after X amount of records and see if I can get better performance - thanks